# Improve the displaying time(-out) of Information Dialog when Vorting an Question!

Tags: feature-request

I thought really everytime since I got an stackoverflow user that I have not enought reputation to upvote already high-voted answers! So I tought I need more reputation so that my upvote will count....

Today I thought okay let's catch this information dialog with an screenshot to read the whole message. Gotcha - a huge information was not accessible to me until now!

**Can the displaying time adjusted to 2,5 seconds?**

[image: because I can't read this in the given time of ~1 sec.]

Comment: The other popups like this one also go away too quickly IMHO, eg. the 'Please leave a comment when downvoting' one.

Comment: I suggest. These informations are great but you miss them because they disappaer to fast. Increasing this displaying time would make a huge positiv change to learn stackoverflow better known - even faster.